# Modify php code to pass a page id as a parameter in order to create a breadcrumb

Tags: php, functions, ajax, breadcrumb

I use a function to create the breadcrumb in my pages and it works:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    $currentBefore = '<li><a>';
    $currentAfter = '</a></li>';
    if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() || is_paged() ) {
        echo '<nav class="breadcrumb"><ul>';
        global $post;
        if ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
            echo $currentBefore;
            the_title();
            echo $currentAfter; }
        elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
            $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
            $breadcrumbs = array();
            while ($parent_id) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                $breadcrumbs[] = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a></li>';
                $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
            }
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
            foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb;
            echo $currentBefore;
            the_title();
            echo $currentAfter;
        }
        echo '</ul></nav>';
    }
}
```

But I would like this function to take a post_id (id of a page) as parameter in order to use it in a AJAX function that create the breadcrumb for that page:

```
function the_ajax_breadcrumb($post_id) {
    ob_start();
    $args = array('page_id' => $post_id);
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $currentBefore = '<li><a>';
    $currentAfter = '</a></li>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() || is_paged() ) {
            echo '<nav class="breadcrumb"><ul>';
            if ( is_page() && !$the_query->post->post_parent ) {
                echo $currentBefore;
                the_title();
                echo $currentAfter;
            }
            elseif ( is_page() && $the_query->post->post_parent ) {
                $parent_id  = $the_query->post->post_parent;
                $breadcrumbs = array();
                while ($parent_id) {
                    $page = get_page($parent_id);
                    $breadcrumbs[] = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a></li>';
                    $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
                }
                $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
                foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb;
                echo $currentBefore;
                the_title();
                echo $currentAfter;
            }
            else {
                echo '<li>nope</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul></nav>';
        }
    }
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    return $result;
}
```

But it outputs 'nope' (the else condition) ... What am I missing here to make this work? Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to remove 'is_page() && ' in both the if and the elseif

```
function the_ajax_breadcrumb($post_id) {
    ob_start();
    $args = array('page_id' => $post_id);
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $currentBefore = '<li><a>';
    $currentAfter = '</a></li>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() || is_paged() ) {
            echo '<nav class="breadcrumb"><ul>';
            if ( !$the_query->post->post_parent ) {
                echo $currentBefore;
                the_title();
                echo $currentAfter;
            }
            elseif ( $the_query->post->post_parent ) {
                $parent_id  = $the_query->post->post_parent;
                $breadcrumbs = array();
                while ($parent_id) {
                    $page = get_page($parent_id);
                    $breadcrumbs[] = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a></li>';
                    $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
                }
                $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
                foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb;
                echo $currentBefore;
                the_title();
                echo $currentAfter;
            }
            else {
                echo '<li>nope</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul></nav>';
        }
    }
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    return $result;
}
```